# How to spread a div to cover available space in a parent container?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a div container and that container is dynamically resized by third-party JavaScript code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        ...some content...
    </div>

    <div class="body">
        ...body content...
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any CSS way how to let the body div spread all the available horizontal and vertical space of the parent container?

Note that I can't set any fixed height on the header div because its content is generated on the fly and it's not always the same height.

Comment: a jsFiddle will make it much easier to help you and better understand what you want to achieve..

Comment: Is the container a known height?

Comment: header `float:left` body `height:100%;width:100%` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSS Flexbox](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/) can do it even if the height of the container isn't known/set explicitly:

```css
.container {
    width: 348px; /* random value to simulate being set by JavaScript */
    border: 1px solid black; /* this is here just for demonstration purposes */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}

.body {
    background: tomato;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        ...some content...
    </div>

    <div class="body">
        ...body content...
        <br/>
        more.
        <p>asdf yeah a paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `height:100%` on the expanding element. Interesting. Nice trick.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks; I tried your way first (`flex: 1;`), but I think I was trying to put flex-direction on the wrong element. So I kept digging for another way because I couldn't figure out my mistake :-P

Answer (score 1):

flexbox can do that if the height is known.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 150px; /* or whatever including % values */
}

.header {
    background: plum;
}

.body {
    flex:1
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.header {
  background: plum;
}
.body {
  background: #c0ffee;
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur vitae laudantium rerum provident delectus ipsa sed, fugiat exercitationem distinctio, asperiores assumenda, eius esse ut. Consequuntur!
  </div>

  <div class="body">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </div>

  <div class="body">

  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hm43tubo/) with 100% screen height example.